# CSS: How to set border for a specific table on the page including columns and rows

Tags: html, css

I have page that has 3 tables.

The table that I need has an id "tblContent"

I set the border for the table:

```
#tblContent
{
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid black;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

But this only sets border around the table.

How can I modify CSS to have the border for rows and columns as well?

Answer (score 1):

Add a border to the table cells as well.

```
#tblContent td, #tblContent th {
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

```css
#tblContent {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
#tblContent td,
#tblContent th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table id="tblContent" style="width: 100%">
  <tr>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```